# Changing value of a variable in another scope with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpackjsonp

I like to change the value of this.form.attributes.age outside of the scope of this code running, for example from console of google chrome but since this value is not global i cannot change it, how can I access it globally?

For example I would like to change it on console like this:
this.form.attributes.age = 10;

The break point belongs to the library webpackJsonp and after a Clicking a button it went to onClick event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an id selector and change the value:

**JQuery**

```
$("#formId").attr("age", 22);
```

**Pure javascript**

```
document.getElementById("formId").setAttribute("age", 22);
```

Comment: there are no form on body, form is generated and submitted by jquery so this wont work

Comment: can you put the function where the form is been generated?